# Java Enum group enums by their values

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, enums

Can you help me with solving some thing. I have enum in my java application:

```
   public enum EnumKey {
       ALPHA("group1"), 
       BETA("group2"),
       GAMMA("group3"),
       SIGMA("group2"),
       DELTA("group2")
       // and other values with "group1" or "group2" or "group3", constructors and getters
       private String groupName;
   }
```

I want to get something like `Map<String, List<EnumKey>>`, where `keys` is my specified `groupNames` and `values` is groupped and sorted  by `groupName enumKey list`(I have only three specified groupNames). I hope my question is clear.

Hope you will help me to find an elegant way to do this.

Comment: Hi Jahra, what have you tried? Can you paste an example?

Comment: I can solve this problem only by creating three lists perfoming every group and iterate over `EnumKey.values()` and sort it with if-else. I am looking for short and effective desicion if it exists @reg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should generate the map you need:

```
public static Map<String, List<EnumKey>> crateEnumKeyMap() {
    Map<String, List<EnumKey>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (EnumKey enumKey : EnumKey.values()) {
        List<EnumKey> enumKeyList = map.get(enumKey.getGroupName());
        if (enumKeyList == null) {
            enumKeyList = new ArrayList<>();
            map.put(enumKey.groupName, enumKeyList);
        }
        enumKeyList.add(enumKey);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Just create a map inside your `EnumKey` with the signature you yourself suggested.

In a static code block iterate over all the values in the enum and add them to the map by adding them to the appropriate list if it exists, if not creating the list and then adding it.